# how to read Rss News image <media:thumbnail> in android

Tags: android

Not able to display image in my RSS news reader.

How to read rss news image `<media:thumbnail>` in android please help me this problem

the tag goes like this

```
<media:thumbnail>http://www.bedfordshirenews.co.uk/imagelibrary/ClientImages/Client00004/00082000/00082068.jpg</media:thumbnail>
```

i have seen examples to parse 
but havent seen any thing to parse the one which i have given above.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to parse the whole feed, you'll want to look at either:

1. [SAXParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html)
2. [XmlPullParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html)

**EDIT:** The media thumbnail is typically an attribute of the tag.  So, you can grab it right in the startElement() method of you DefaultHandler:

```
public void startElement(String uri, String name, String qName, Attributes atts) {      
    if (name.trim().equals("thumbnail")) {          
        String thumbnail = atts.getValue("url");            
    }
}
```

Note that you can also check for the qualified name with 3rd argument of startElement.

Comment: actually i am reading Title, descrption and link, i want to dispaly image also<media:thumbnail>, how to read this element from RSS new url

Comment: thank you sir i was googling for 3 days and your solution is the only working one